# iPhone App Store Green Button

Tags: iphone, button

I want to use a green button on my app like the one used on App Store when you select an app to install and press the button "FREE".

Is it possible to use a button like this without a custom image?

Thank you,

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:[Custom UIButton](http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2009/01/iphone-create-uibutton-with-custom.html) You may just need to crop this photo in photoshop: [Appstore Free App Screenshot](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/rolando_2_chapter_1_app_store_screenshot1.jpg) and then just use the cropped photo as the button .png graphic.

Answer (score 3):

No, you're going to need to either whip up some custom drawing code for your button or make the background image in an image editor. All of the pre-made UI elements available to you are in Interface Builder. If you're not seeing what you want there, it's time to customize.